# What are the software for developing J2ME applicatuions for mobile?

Tags: java-me

I'm interested in developing J2ME applications for mobile. Is there any easy-to-use, free software to aid with the development of J2ME applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetBeans is official, free and its evolving. http://netbeans.org/features/javame/

It is not as easy to use as VB6, but will do.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is using simulators like Java ME (a.k.a Sun Microsystems WTK):

Sun Java Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2_01 for CLDC Download (1)  (very stable) or more recently JAVA ME SDK 3.0.5.

Uses a IDE of your preference. 
- Eclipse for Mobile Developers (Eclipse Juno (4.2) Packages) not works correctly with plugin MTJ (Mobile Tool for Java); My suggestion is previous Eclipse edition. Then uses PULSAR edition of Eclipse IDE (2). This edition has the MTJ Plugin.

(1) Java Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2_01
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-135801.html

(2) Eclipse Pulsar edition (to Java ME - Mobile developer)
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/pulsar-mobile-developers/heliossr2